# Loki docker client is not sending logs to Grafana cloud's preconfigured loki datasource

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, grafana-loki

I have followed the steps mentioned here https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/docker-driver/configuration/ for sending logs from docker compose containers to grafana cloud's preconfigured loki datasource.

But unfortunately I'm not able to find any logs dashboard. I have added the url, userid and password as mentioned below but it is not working.
[image]

Here is my docker-compose yaml configured

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  logger:
    image: redis
    logging:
      driver: loki
      options:
        loki-url: "https://<user-id>:configured@<url>/loki/api/v1/push"
        loki-external-labels: "service=redis,env=prd"
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Able to figure out the issue. Access token used is lack of permissions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).